# If $S$ is a symmetric matrix, then rewriting $\int{S:\nabla \phi} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, tensors

I am trying to prove that:

If $S$ is a symmetric matrix, then one can rewrite $\int{S:\nabla \phi} \text{dx}$ as $\int{S:D(\phi)} \text{dx}$, where $D(\phi)$ is the symmetric gradient of $\phi$.

Any kind of hint will be helpful! (Question was to only rewrite the expression, however after looking through some other notes, I believe that putting a condition of $S$ being symmetric should be sufficient?)

Comment: What does the colon $:$ denote here

Comment: @SBF  the colon should denote the 'double contraction' of matrices $A:B = \sum_{i,j} A_{ij}B_{ij}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with the integral. If $S=S^T$ then
\begin{align}
 S : \nabla \phi = \sum_{i,j} S_{ij} \partial_j \phi_i 
&= \frac12\left(\sum_{i,j} S_{ij} \partial_j \phi_i + \sum_{i,j} S_{ij} \partial_j \phi_i\right) \\
&= \frac12 \left(\sum_{i,j} S_{ij} \partial_j \phi_i + \sum_{i,j} S_{\color{red}{ji}} \partial_j \phi_i\right)\\
&= \frac12 \left(\sum_{i,j} S_{ij} \partial_j \phi_i + \sum_{j',i'} S_{i',j'} \partial_{i'} \phi_{j'}\right) \\
&= \sum_{i,j}S_{ij}  \frac12 \left(  \partial_j \phi_i + \partial_i \phi_j \right)\\
&= S : D(\phi).
\end{align}
Or, if you prefer to see less indices, since $A^T:B = A:B^T$
\begin{align} S: \nabla \phi &= \frac12(S + S^T ): \nabla \phi \\ 
&= \frac12\left(S:\nabla \phi +  S^T: \nabla \phi\right) \\
&= \frac12\left(S:\nabla \phi +  S: \nabla \phi^T\right) \\ 
&= S : \frac12(\nabla \phi + \nabla\phi^T)\\ & = S:D(\phi).
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! Could you explain what you did there with the renumbering ($i', j'$)? Also, I think you missed a transpose in the second last line in the first calculation.

Comment: That's just setting $i=j'$ and$j=i'$, so that it looks more like the first sum. And yeah a transpose is missing sorry